# Quicksort occasionally not completing?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've made a bunch of attempts at a quicksort algorithm, which I just can't seem to make work. This code is the closest I've gotten, except that it about one in five times it doesn't fully sort - it outputs something like `266, 186, 219, 276, 357, 405, 686, 767, 834, 862`. I've tried to find a commonality between all the sets of numbers that do this, but I can't find anything. I've spent many hours stepping through it with a debugger but can't see anything (although I feel like I'm missing something obvious). What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int left, int right) {
    int i = left - 1, j = right, v = arr.get(right);
    if(right - i == 0 || right - i == 1)return;

    for(;;) {
        while(arr.get(++i) < v);
        while(v < arr.get(--j) && j != 0)
            if(j == 1)break;
        if(i >= j)break;

        Collections.swap(arr, i, j);
    }
    Collections.swap(arr, i, right);

    sort(arr, left, i - 1);
    sort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Comment: your first number is what isn't sorting, so that's where I'd start to look

Comment: Trace through it on paper step by step. Record down at each step the value of each variable and the array changes. Do not write down what you think it should be, write down what the instructions actually say. When you trace through it this way you get a much better understanding of things.

Comment: I'll go do that now, thank you. I'd put aside doing that until now because of how many iterations it's going through (meaning hundreds of lines on paper).

Comment: I also get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException every once in a while.  I am thinking you not doing your pivoting correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. Seems to only happen with an odd number of elements. I might be, yeah. I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: You should instrument the code so that after a partition it checks that the largest element in the left subarray does not exceed the smallest element in the right subarray.

Comment: I had considered that, but that should be unnecessary if the algorithm was written correctly, yeah?

Comment: Why are you testing `j` against 0 and 1 in the `while` loop? Surely it should be something involving `left`.

Comment: I suppose it would make more sense if it was against i, wouldn't it? I was just making sure j would never go below 0 and throw an OutOfBoundsException - which it still sometimes does on that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two things to your code to get it to work:

at beginning of method set `j = right +1`
and move `v = arr.get(right)` to after first if statement.

Should look something like this:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int left, int right) {
        int i = left - 1;
        int j = right + 1;
        if (right - i == 0 || right - i == 1) return;
        int v = arr.get(right);

        for (;;) {
            while (arr.get(++i) < v);
            while (v < arr.get(--j) && j != 0)
                if (j == 1) break;
            if (i >= j) break;

            Collections.swap(arr, i, j);
        }
        Collections.swap(arr, i, right);

        sort(arr, left, i - 1);
        sort(arr, i, right);
    }
```

But this was really unreadable code, you should read the book CleanCode.

Comment: I'll try that next time I get a chance, but as for my code being "really unreadable", all you did was separate the variable declarations at the top.

Comment: And why List instead of ArrayList?

Comment: Changed List back to ArrayList did that to be able to write a unit test without my IDE yelling tons of warnings.

Comment: @IHazABone, `List`, so that the method will sort both Lists and ArrayLists, as ArrayList extends List. One method to do both is good.

Comment: As for unreadable I am not sure that `j = right +1` is the correct thing to do since I couldn't understand the code.

Comment: It was a while ago I studied implementation details of sorting algorithms, so my changes might not give a pure QuickSort. Also if you want your own algorithm you should probably work with arrays instead of List it usually wins in speed.

Comment: Yeah I'm just using Lists right now because of the easy Collections#swap().